# Toggle vim setting with vimscript function

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a function that toggles the `set list` attribute, in order to map the function later to a command.

I have the following written:

```
function! ShowMarksToggle()
  if (&list == 0)
    set list
  else
    set nolist
  endif
endfunction
```

The function gets parsed and runs (with `:call ShowMarksToggle()`) without any warning, however the settings doesn't gets toggled.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you put this in your vimrc? And did you try to toggle it with a keybinding?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`:set list!`

Body must be at least 30. You entered 10.

Comment: ... or remarked on what's wrong in the OP's attempt.